# Xpath subscript returning all nodes, not just the requested one

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying the following XPath:

```
//*[local-name()='SN102'][1]
```

Using XPathTester, I saved my scenario 
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/94ee37e08960247a7bf0619d38c52bee

Not every HL1Loop has a SN102.
Otherwise, I could this:

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1'][1]//*[local-name()='SN102']
```

I have simplified the sample data down to the following:

```
<ns0:X12_00401_856 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
  <ns0:HLLoop1>
   <ns0:SN1>
      <SN102>1</SN102>
      <SN103>EA</SN103>
      <SN108>AC</SN108>
    </ns0:SN1>
  </ns0:HLLoop1>
  <ns0:HLLoop1>
    <ns0:SN1>
      <SN102>2</SN102>
      <SN103>EA</SN103>
      <SN108>AC</SN108>
    </ns0:SN1>
  </ns0:HLLoop1>
</ns0:X12_00401_856>
```

The result is coming back with all nodes, not just the first one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<SN102>1</SN102>
<SN102>2</SN102>
</result>
```

How do I select the first node only.  Seems simply, and I'm sure I've done it before, but not working today.

I have a "Vendor Simulator" program that is building fake 856 data to send back, and I want to increase the first quantity only to force some error handling logic.

Comment: I'm quite sure your simplified document does not reflect the real situation. The behavior you describe can only occur when `HLLoop1` elements are the respective first such elements within separate parents.

Comment: This is a FAQ.  The fact that `[]` has higher precedence than `//` in XPath misleads many.  Without an overriding `()`, `//a[1]` selects all `a` elements that are the first child of its parent.  See duplicate links for further details and discussions.

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is in a note within the XPath specification itself: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev

Comment: @michael.hor257k:  Lots of good examples in the original, simple XPath spec, agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select the first element of the whole nodelist

```
(//*[local-name()='SN102'])[1]
```

The original query  `//*[local-name()='SN102'][1]` would have selected the first SN102 if there had been several siblings of the same name.